# jQuery - Adding elements and affecting the HTML of a different element

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to change the HTML of a div every time a div element is added within the existing HTML? The end goal is to have it where if a user selects the "add" button, another div calculates the how many divs have been added and inputs the number elsewhere (ideally into a different div).

e.g. A div should display the number of added elements, based on the user's adds. If the user removes elements, the number should now reflect the new total of the number of elements.

What would be the best practice for this technique?

The jQuery:

```
var content = $('#contentElement');
var count = $('#contentElement .numberElement > span');

var addButton = $('#buttonElement.add');
var removeButton = $('#buttonElement.remove');

var block = $('#blockElement');
var newBlock = '<div id="blockElement"><span>Added Block</span></div>'
var lastBlock = $('#blockElement').last();

$('#blockElement').css('backgorund', 'purple');

count.html(0);

function addBlock() {
    $(newBlock).insertAfter($('#buttonContainer'));
}

addButton.on('click', function(event){
    addBlock();
});

function removeBlock() {
    var lastBlock = $('#blockElement').last();
    lastBlock.remove();
}

removeButton.on('click', function(event){
    removeBlock();
});
```

The current/live version is located on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwierzba/02shzzz6/).

This may better help display the end objective.

Comment: You're creating (and have) elements with the same Id. Have the created divs have the same class instead and have your counter count the number of divs with that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done it using your original JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/02shzzz6/15/

```
var blockElementCount = $(".blockElement").length;
addButton.on('click', function(event){
    addBlock();
    blockElementCount++;
    updateCounter();
});
function updateCounter(){
    $(".numberElement > span").text(blockElementCount);
}
```

Take note I also changed it to use classes because you were inserting new elements with the same ID.

Comment: Maybe it's just my browser, but this seems to have broken the remove button and a bit of the css.

Comment: Sorry about that have fixed it up accordingly.

Comment: Np. This is probably a cleaner solution than mine as it's taking the count directly from the DOM as opposed to having a JS variable that isn't really in connection with the DOM.

Comment: Great if it solved your problems, please accept the answer :)

Comment: I'm not the one who asked the question. I'm the guy who posted the other solution.

Answer (score 1):

I moved it into codepen because I like it better and commented up my changes. Look at the comments to see where I made changes. All you needed was an iterator and a bit of code in the add function to rewrite the number like this.

```
count.html(elementCount);
```

http://codepen.io/supah_frank/pen/uzFve